# Using ajax long polling to update a response on my page from an external API

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, long-polling

I have the following **ajax long polling script**

```
(function poll(){
    $.ajax({ url: "<?php echo URL::to('/internal/v1/checkTxn');  ?>", success: function(data){
        //Update your dashboard gauge
        console.log(data.status);  //Data is getting logged
        if(data.status == 'success'){  //This condition is not being checked
            console.log('suucesful'); //Not coming
        }
    }, dataType: "json", complete: poll, timeout: 1000 });
})();
```

The **backend PHP** code is as follows

```
 if(isset($_POST['status']) && $_POST['status']){
            $data = ['status'=>$_POST['status']];
            $json = json_encode( $data );
           echo $json;
        }
```

**Flow**

1. When I render the page, the ajax script runs and waits for response. When I checked the network tab, ajax was endlessly making requests to the URL specified.
2. I get a form post from an external website to the backend PHP which I need to push to the jquery.

But when a post is happening, nothing is being logged in the console. But if I hard code some values in the **$json** and echo it, its coming up in the console.

I am facing two issues

1. When a post happens on the PHP script, its not coming up in the ajax code.
2. When I hard code (simulated the response posted by the external form post) the **$json** and echo it, its coming up in the console, but the condition for **data.status== 'success'** is  not getting checked.

What is wrong in this. Am I missing something?

**UPDATE**

> ```
> I could fix the "condition not being checked" as there was something wrong the json being echoed.
>
> Now to avoid confusion, the flow for this
>
> User open the page, 
>
> > The ajax starts the long polling process to my PHP code, waiting for a
> > response.User enters payment details in a form which is my html,clicks on pay, a pop up appears
> > which renders the banks login page (Payment gateway).After user entering all
> > details in the pop up (banks page), bank sents a server to server call about the status of
> > transaction to my notificationURL
> > ('mydomain.com/internal.v1/checkTxn'). As soon as I get a POST on this
> > URL(I will close the pop up), my ajax polling should get the data posted to my PHP and there by
> > I will show the status of TXN to the user on the same card form he entered his details earlier and
> > the pop window closes. The response here is returned by my PHP code to the ajax.
> The
> > post coming to my PHP code is a server to server post which is posted
> > by a Payment Gateway.
> ```

Comment: you should do JSON.parse(data) to convert them to JS object in ajax on success because you get data in JSON  and i guess (function(){...}(jQuery); you have to pass jQuery as parameter to IIFE

Comment: Posting from an external site may not work. Ajax is generally limited to the same site.

Comment: @Brett No , expernal site posts to my PHP script and then the ajax calls the php script which is on my server

Answer (score 0):

If you are using long polling, you could have a cache issue.
First, when your post comes to your system, check that checkTxn changes.
Last, you can add a random parameter (by adding date in millis, for example) in url query, you will not use it, but your server will think your requests are different.

Please, check it and let us know.

@Edit:  Sure @Ajeesh, I'll explain it:

```
(function poll(){
    $.ajax({ url: "<?php echo URL::to('/internal/v1/checkTxn');  ?>?_ts=" + new Date().getTime(), success: function(data){
        //Update your dashboard gauge
        console.log(data.status);  //Data is getting logged
        if(data.status == 'success'){  //This condition is not being checked
            console.log('suucesful'); //Not coming
        }
    }, dataType: "json", complete: poll, timeout: 1000 });
})();
```

By doing this, cache will not be used, because all queries are different for your server/browser.

On the other hand, I ask you for any changes in your page when you receive the POST, so, if not, your ajax will never receive the notification, do you know what I mean?

Comment: @Tisktkle Can you please elaborate?

Comment: By following your comments, is not possible to get a POST request in your page from your ajax poll, or at least is not an easy duty. Your ajax is getting html/json data from the page render process. If you don't change the page data, it will receive the same forever.

Answer (score 0):

**1. let's debug this:**

set your ajax error call back,

```
$(function(){

        (function poll(){
            $.ajax({ url: "http://tinyissue.localhost.com/test.php", success: function(data){
                //Update your dashboard gauge
                console.log(data.status);  //Data is getting logged
                if(data.status == 'success'){  //This condition is not being checked
                    console.log('suucesful'); //Not coming
                }
            },error:function(err){
                console.info('error fired...');
                console.info(err);
            }, dataType: "json", complete: poll, timeout: 1000 });
        })();

    });
```

run this, you will get console

```
error fired...
Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}
```

**2. Why went to error callback:**

Why ajax response `status` is **200** and `statusText` is **"OK"** , `error` callback still fired instead of `success`?

Your AJAX request contains the following setting:

```
dataType: "json"
```

The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) states that jQuery:

> Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. (...)
>   The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is
>   rejected and a parse error is thrown.

This means that if server returns **invalid JSON** with a **200 OK** status then jQuery fires the error function and set the textStatus parameter to "parsererror".

Solution: make sure that the server returns **valid JSON**. It is worth noting that an empty response is also considered invalid JSON; you could return {} or null for example which validate as JSON.

**3. Why ajax return invalid JSON:**

In your mind, at server side, you checked the `$_POST['status']` to make sure last call success in the loop poll, only `$_POST['status']` is set, you will echo json, or it echo nothing.

But, unfortunately, at the beginning of the call loop, **the first time** the ajax called, you didn't set `status` to post. Then it echo nothing, then it went `error` callback, also went `complete` callback, then call again without `status` to post. See, it went a bad cycle.

**4. Solution:**

Set a `status` value to post at the first ajax call.

```
$(function(){

        (function poll(){
            var status = 'success';
            $.ajax({ url: "http://tinyissue.localhost.com/test.php", success: function(data){
                //Update your dashboard gauge
                console.log(data.status);  //Data is getting logged
                status = data.status;
                if(data.status == 'success'){  //This condition is not being checked
                    console.log('suucesful'); //Not coming
                }
            },error:function(err){
                console.info('error fired...');
                console.info(err);
                status = 'error';
            }, type:'post',dataType: "json", data:{status:status}, complete: poll, timeout: 1000 });
        })();

    });
```

Comment: I think there is a confusion in this. The POST is not done by the Ajax. Its done by an external form post. AJAX-> POLLING->PHP<- POST from external form post

Comment: I could fix the response not coming thing. Still the issue in not getting the data which is posted by an external form post still persists.

Comment: A little confused...Every connect from client to server create `$_POST` for themselves, how could ajax request get the `$_POST` variable of the form post request?it's impossible...Or I misunderstood?

Comment: You are mis understood I guess. I will update the question

Comment: I have updated the question in the end,Please see the flow

Comment: Rethink your flow, How about this : When gate way callback your server, just modify you database field, and your ajax request check that field every time, until recognize it changed?

Comment: Its a overhead. Ajax will be hitting my  database all the time which will create a huge problem. I really don't wanna do that

Comment: What you want is: ajax and gateway callback call the **same** url, and let ajax know when gateway callback with post data status? If so, that's impossible...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111493/discussion-between-yin-gang-and-ajeesh).