# Emitted value cannot be added to DIV express.js socket.io

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have the following **app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
// var responseHandlerRouter = require('./routes/responseHandlerRouter.js');

routes = require('./routes');

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});

io = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/socket.io').listen(server);

app.use('/', routes(io));
```

**routes.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

module.exports = function (io) {

    // all of this router's configurations

    router.get('/login', function (req, res, next) {
        io.emit('notification', 'news');
        res.end('well finally I am here');
    });

    return router;

}
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>

        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/login');

        socket.on('notification', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id='messages'></ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I do a get on the URL, it should emit but its not happening. Its not showing any errors, but fails silently.

Is there anything wrong?

**Update**

[image: "news" was being sent from the router successfully.]

I want to show the "news" in the div.
but I am not able to append this as follows

```
   .... socket.on('notification', function (data) {
               $('#messages').html(data);
            });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <ul id='messages'></ul>
        </body>....
```

**Will make this eligible for bounty**

Comment: Do you actually request `/login` with ajax?

Comment: No. I have just did a get using postman or by going to localhost:3000/login through the browser.

Comment: does your html page is actually a login page? so that you request `/login` and the login.html renders, if so, socket needs time to connect

Comment: No this is just a pure test and the /login is just a test route which i made. I just have all this 3 scripts, there is nothing else. All i wanted to do is, when a request comes on route, I need to make changes to DOM. Also  socket.on('notification', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });  , the console.log is not showing any value when i hit the /login url thouhg its coming in the frames in network tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using the router in a wrong way.

Not sure, but I think that `app.use('/login', routes(io))` instead of what you've got should do the trick.

In your implementation your router receives only GETs to `'/'`

**EDIT:** although the answer is accepted, the real solution is in the comments below (wrong connection url specified)

Comment: I could fix the issue. I am getting values in the network tab. But Im not able to alert or append that value to div

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly Done! Please check

Comment: @Ajeesh are you sure the logic is okay in this code? you are handling an http-request, why not just return the data in the response and not use sockets?)

Comment: @MikhailDudin My use case is different. If you see this question by me you will get to know why I wanted to do this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37129486/using-ajax-long-polling-to-update-a-response-on-my-page-from-an-external-api . I have a php backend which is not capable of scaling long polling, so using websockets. Please check the question to get a clear picture on what Im trying to do

Comment: @Ajeesh you've probably mistaken in having specified the wrong namespace for your socket conneciton: "var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/login');" - try to remove "/login" in this expression

Comment: Awesome dude!! You saved my day!!!! Thanks a ton!! I will set some bounty and will give that :))

Comment: It's been a pleasure to help you!